# brightway2 testing: tearing down temporary test projects (fixtures)

Tags: python, pytest, brightway

I am writing some brightway2 extensions, and am writing corresponding tests in pytest. I am having trouble with the teardown portion of the tests.

Like other brightway2 tests, I use the @bw2tests decorator when creating my fixture, see [here](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/5acd4456f0febb9c7b1b8af51b2d859fd63e96db/bw2data/tests.py#lines-36). This allows a project to be created in a temp dir, and generally configures brightway2 properly for testing.

My fixture looks something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
@bw2test
def basic():
    """Pytest fixture with test bw2 project with test data to use in test"""

    # Write test data...
    # For example, for the biosphere Database:
    biosphere = Database("biosphere")
    biosphere.register()
    biosphere.write({
        ("biosphere", "1"): {
            'categories': ['things'],
            'exchanges': [],
            'name': 'an emission',
            'type': 'emission',
            'unit': 'kg'
        })

    # Once I have created all the data I need, 
    # I yield the data I need for my test functions...
    yield {'project': projects.current, 'method_name': method_name}

    # Once my tests are done, I would like to tear down the project
    projects.delete_project(projects.current, delete_dir=True)
```

This all works until the teardown: since the project is the only one in the temp directory, I get `ValueError: Can't delete only remaining project`.

If I don't tear down, however, the new test directories that get created each time I run a test stay on disk. They are not that big (100kB), but I still think they shouldn't be around.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `projects` function, just nuke the directory completely with `shutil.rmtree`. This is now done automatically in `bw2data` versus 3.5.1 (released 5.9.2019).

Comment: I updated bw2data, and the attempt to nuke the directory is resisted: 

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  

  File "C:\mypy\anaconda\envs\bw_dev_fall_2019\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe  
    os.unlink(fullname)  
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:  
 'C:\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpvzwb4z96\\data\\default.c21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682\\lci\\databases.db'

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/issues/3), and is marked as high priority (as it is causing the CI to fail :)